TypeOrm doesn't rebuild table properly
I'm using TypeOrm with Node.js. I also have a MySQL database.
Something strange keeps happening every time I restart my server.

I start the Node server on my local machine "npm run start".
TypeOrm syncs the data. All the tables work. Except Notifications. It tries to recreate the table, but it fails half way. Therefore the tables' fields don't match the Notifications's entity's structure.
As only three columns are recreated (instead of 10), I get the ER_BAD_FIELD_ERROR in any other script that tries to use the Notifications table.
If I delete the Notifications table and "npm run start" again, everything works fine.

Here's my DataSource configuration:
type: "mysql",
host: process.env.MYSQL_HOSTNAME,
  port: 3306,
  username: process.env.MYSQL_USERNAME,
  password: process.env.MYSQL_PASSWORD,
  socketPath: process.env.MYSQL_SOCKET_PATH,
  database: process.env.MYSQL_DATABASE,
  synchronize: true,
  logging: false,
  connectTimeout: 20000,
  dropSchema: false,
  entities: [
    Users,
    Notifications,
    etc...
  ],
  migrations: [],
  subscribers: [], 
});

Here is the entity for Notifications:

@Index("notifications_id_UNIQUE", ["id"], { unique: true })
@Index("createdAt", ["createdAt"])
@Index("userId", ["userId"])
@Entity("notifications", { schema: "xxx", orderBy: {
  createdAt: "DESC",
} })
export class Notifications { 
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn({ type: "int", name: "id" })
  id: number;

  @Column("varchar", { name: "notificationId", nullable: false, unique: true })
  notificationId: string;

  @Column("tinyint", { name: "notificationType", nullable: true })
  notificationType: number | null;

  @Column("text", { name: "message", nullable: true })
  message: string | null;

  @Column("varchar", { name: "country", nullable: true, length: 2 })
  country: string | null;

  @Column("varchar", { name: "userId", nullable: true })
  userId: string | null;

  @Column("tinyint", { name: "contentType", nullable: true })
  contentType: number | null;

  @Column("varchar", { name: "contentId", nullable: true })
  contentId: string | null;

  @Column("bigint", { name: "createdAt" })
  createdAt: number;
  
  @Column("tinyint", { name: "isRead", default:0, nullable: false })
  isRead: number;
}

Why does the rebuild fail for this table?
Thanks

"Typeorm rebuilds my tables (I don't really know why)" Seems this is important.

ER_BAD_FIELD_ERROR Is there any more information?

ER_BAD_FIELD_ERROR happense because it doesn't rebuild my data properly. How can I prevent TypeOrm from rebuilding everything every time I restart the server?

We need some context. Could you show us the command you ran, the output, and particularly the context for the ER_BAD_FIELD_ERROR? Has the build ever completed successfully?

I don't run any script to get the error.

I start the Node server on my local machine
TypeOrm syncs the data. All the tables work. Except Notifications. It tries to recreate the table, but it fails half way. Therefore the tables' fields don't match the Notifications's entity's structure.
As only three columns are recreated (instead of 10), I get the ER_BAD_FIELD_ERROR.
If I delete the Notifications table and "npm run start" again, everything works fine.

Thanks!

So ER_BAD_FIELD_ERROR comes from when you try to query notifications, that makes sense. It creates a Notifications table, but it's missing some columns? Which columns are made? Can you show us show create table notifications? Is there an error message about the failed create table, or perhaps an error log?

Thank you so much... It only creates: Id, message, country, createdAt, title.  I don't know where to get the TypeOrm logs. :-(

After I get the error, here is the show create table notifications:
```'CREATE TABLE notifications (
id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
message text COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci,
country varchar(2) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
createdAt bigint NOT NULL,
title varchar(150) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (id),
UNIQUE KEY id_UNIQUE (id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci'


Here is information on logging in TypeORM. That should reveal the problem pretty quick.

I'll give it a try. In the meantime, I'll set sync to false. Thanks!!!!

I tried everything. The only thing that worked for me was to create new tables with different names to replace those that were messed up when rebuilt.
